# Using an AVPlayer returns a "non-Multipath connection" error

Tags: swift, xcode, url, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm using AVKit to play a youtube URL.

I have this code inside a button action:

```
 @IBAction func trailerButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let youtubeUrl = youtubeURL else { return }
    let player = AVPlayer(url: youtubeUrl)
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player

    present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }
}
```

The URL is valid, but when I press the button, the video doesn't stop loading and I'm getting this message on Debug area:

> nw_endpoint_flow_copy_multipath_subflow_counts Called on non-Multipath connection

**Edit:**

I found that AVPlayer doesn't support youtube URL

Comment: I having the same issue. The video is not playing and I get that as output. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: This is the issue i think: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/improving_network_reliability_using_multipath_tcp

Comment: okey i got it. Its a network issue. try with this video : https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4

Comment: Now, Ι didn't get the previous error. I get this: NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002

Comment: Then it's for sure your connection. Can you try from a different connection

Comment: You mean another wifi?

Comment: Yes. Or a direct cable connection

Comment: I tried with cellular on my device but with no result.

Comment: Edit: Now is playing with "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4". I found that AVPlayer doesn't support youtube URL

Answer (score 6):

I would say this log isn't necessarily relevant. I was getting this error when trying to playback on the simulator but it wasn't happening on a real device.

Comment: The error log is unlikely related to your real issue though I think

Comment: nw_endpoint_flow_copy_multipath_subflow_counts Called on non-Multipath connection
 Getting this error

Answer (score 3):

One workaround would be to use a 12.4.x simulator as it does not exhibit this issue. Only the 13.x simulators are showing this error. It happens to repeatedly that it slows down Simulator to a craw until all requested tracks have been buffered.

To combat this while testing, I am either not turning on `AVPlayer` or I am only buffering a short track.

To cut down on the number of errors try initing your `AVPlayer` like so:

```
var avPlayer : AVPlayer = AVPlayer()
```

This may cut down the errors by 30%.